# ssh and issuing remote commands

Tags: command, router

All,

I am pretty knowledgeable but there is one thing I am having trouble trying to figure out. I am not trying to ssh a remote command into a Unix box but a router. This router is a Alcatel 7750 but I will give you an example of a Cisco router so that what I am trying to do is more familiar looking..  What I am trying to do is issue a command  using ssh But I need to do a "conf t" so that it goes into edit mode then issue the next command I need.. what I am wondering if it is possible to send the command "conf t" then issue  so that it can issue the next command? Like a carriage return after the "conf t"  something like conf t \r next command all within the one ssh instance? I have tried everything I can think of which isn't as much as a real programmer like most of you guys..  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) is exactly what you need. It is very well fitted to automate interactive operation.